# keras LSTM feeding input with the right shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting some data from a pandas dataframe with the following shape

```
df.head()
>>>
Value USD   Drop 7  Up 7    Mean Change 7   Change      Predict
0.06480     2.0     4.0     -0.000429       -0.00420    4
0.06900     1.0     5.0     0.000274        0.00403     2
0.06497     1.0     5.0     0.000229        0.00007     2
0.06490     1.0     5.0     0.000514        0.00200     2
0.06290     2.0     4.0     0.000229        -0.00050    3
```

The first 5 columns are intended to be the `X` and predict the `y`. This is how I preprocess the data for the model

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Convert a Pandas dataframe to the x,y inputs that TensorFlow needs
def to_xy(df, target):
    result = []
    for x in df.columns:
        if x != target:
            result.append(x)
    # find out the type of the target column.  Is it really this hard? :(
    target_type = df[target].dtypes
    target_type = target_type[0] if hasattr(target_type, '__iter__') else target_type
    # Encode to int for classification, float otherwise. TensorFlow likes 32 bits.
    if target_type in (np.int64, np.int32):
        # Classification
        dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[target])
        return df.as_matrix(result).astype(np.float32), dummies.as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
    else:
        # Regression
        return df.as_matrix(result).astype(np.float32), df.as_matrix([target]).astype(np.float32)

# Encode text values to indexes(i.e. [1],[2],[3] for red,green,blue).
def encode_text_index(df, name):
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    df[name] = le.fit_transform(df[name])
    return le.classes_

df['Predict'].value_counts()
>>>
4    1194
3     664
2     623
0     405
1      14
Name: Predict, dtype: int64

predictions = encode_text_index(df, "Predict")
predictions
>>>
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)

X,y = to_xy(df,"Predict")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)

X_train
>>>
array([[ 6.4800002e-02,  2.0000000e+00,  4.0000000e+00, -4.2857142e-04,
        -4.1999999e-03],
       [ 6.8999998e-02,  1.0000000e+00,  5.0000000e+00,  2.7414286e-04,
         4.0300000e-03],
       [ 6.4970002e-02,  1.0000000e+00,  5.0000000e+00,  2.2857143e-04,
         7.0000002e-05],
       ...,
       [ 9.5987000e+02,  5.0000000e+00,  2.0000000e+00, -1.5831429e+01,
        -3.7849998e+01],
       [ 9.9771997e+02,  5.0000000e+00,  2.0000000e+00, -1.6948572e+01,
        -1.8250000e+01],
       [ 1.0159700e+03,  5.0000000e+00,  2.0000000e+00, -1.3252857e+01,
        -7.1700001e+00]], dtype=float32)

y_train
>>>
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)

X_train[1]
>>>
array([6.8999998e-02, 1.0000000e+00, 5.0000000e+00, 2.7414286e-04,
       4.0300000e-03], dtype=float32)

X_train.shape
>>>
(2320, 5)

X_train[1].shape
>>>
(5,)
```

and finally the LSTM model (also it might look like not the best way to write one so will appreciate a rewrite of the inner layers as well if that's the case)

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_shape=(None, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=X_train.shape))
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
#model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

#model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-2, patience=15, verbose=1, mode='auto')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="best_weights.hdf5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True) # save best model

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[monitor,checkpointer], verbose=2, epochs=1000)
model.load_weights('best_weights.hdf5') # load weights from best model
```

running this throws this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-a17835a382f6> in <module>()
     15 checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="best_weights.hdf5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True) # save best model
     16 
---> 17 model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[monitor,checkpointer], verbose=2, epochs=1000)
     18 model.load_weights('best_weights.hdf5') # load weights from best model

c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    948             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    949             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 950             batch_size=batch_size)
    951         # Prepare validation data.
    952         do_validation = False

c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    747             feed_input_shapes,
    748             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 749             exception_prefix='input')
    750 
    751         if y is not None:

c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    125                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    126                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 127                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    128                 if not check_batch_axis:
    129                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_48_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2320, 5)
```

I've tried a lot of variations of the X_train input shape but every single one throws some error, I also checked the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) but it wasn't clear on how the data should be fed to the model

### Attempt No. 1 from Suggestions

First is reshaping X_train

```
data = np.resize(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=data.shape))
```

this fails with an error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_52: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

suggested I feed it in as

```
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
```

that throws the same error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_63: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

### Sugestion 2

use the default X,y from pandas

```
y = df['Predict']
X = df[['Value USD', 'Drop 7', 'Up 7', 'Mean Change 7', 'Change']]

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)
```

also that LSTM expect input in the following way `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`

so I tried this

```
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(100, 100, X_train.shape)))
```

which throws this error

```
TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.
```

and a different way

```
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(100, 100, X_train[1].shape)))
```

returns the same error

```
TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set up a LSTM ( stateful or stateless ? ) with *multiple features*, the features are the columns `Value USD   Drop 7  Up 7    Mean Change 7   Change` in your dataframe. A similar problem is in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6471

Keras LSTMs accept input as `(batch_size (number of samples processed at a time),timesteps,features) = (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)` As you have 5 features `input_dim = features = 5`. i do not know your entire data so i can not say more. The relation of `number_of_samples` ( *number of rows in your dataframe* ) and `batch_size` is in http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/, `batch_size` is the number of samples ( rows ) processed at a time ( [doubts regarding batch size and time steps in RNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381450/doubts-regarding-batch-size-and-time-steps-in-rnn) ) :

> Said differently, whenever you train or test your LSTM, you first have
>   to build your input matrix X of shape `nb_samples, timesteps, input_dim`
>   where your `batch size` divides `nb_samples`. For instance, if
>   `nb_samples=1024` and `batch_size=64`, it means that your model will
>   receive blocks of 64 samples, compute each output (whatever the number
>   of timesteps is for every sample), average the gradients and propagate
>   it to update the parameters vector.

source : http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/

batch size is important for training

> A batch size of 1 means that the model will be fit using *online
>   training* (as opposed to *batch training* or *mini-batch training*). As a
>   result, it is expected that the model fit will have some variance.

source : https://machinelearningmastery.com/stateful-stateless-lstm-time-series-forecasting-python/

`timesteps` is the number of timesteps / past network states you want to look back on, there is a maximal value for LSTMs of about 200-500 ( Vanishing Gradient problem ) for performance reason maximal value is about 200 ( https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2057 )

splitting is easier ( [Selecting multiple columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe) ) :

```
y = df['Predict']
X = df[['Value USD','Drop 7','Up 7','Mean Change 7', 'Change']]
```

in **https://www.kaggle.com/mknorps/titanic-with-decision-trees** is code for modifying data types

**updated :**

to get rid of these errors you have to *reshape* the training data like in **[Error when checking model input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (339732, 29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704435/error-when-checking-model-input-expected-lstm-1-input-to-have-3-dimensions-but)** ( also contains reshaping code for more than 1 timestep ). i post entire code that worked for me because this question is less trivial than it appeared on first sight ( **note the number of `[` and `]` that indicate the dimension of an array, when reshaping** ) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.read_csv('/path/data_lstm.dat')

y = df['Predict']
X = df[['Value USD', 'Drop 7', 'Up 7', 'Mean Change 7', 'Change']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)

X_train_array = X_train.values  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array-preserving-index )
y_train_array = y_train.values.reshape(4,1)

X_test_array = X_test.values
y_test_array = y_test.values


# reshaping to fit batch_input_shape=(4,1,5) batch_size, timesteps, number_of_features , batch_size can be varied batch_input_shape=(2,1,5), = (1,1,5),... is also working

X_train_array = np.reshape(X_train_array, (X_train_array.shape[0], 1, X_train_array.shape[1]))
#>>> X_train_array    NOTE THE NUMBER OF [ and ] !!
#array([[[ 6.480e-02,  2.000e+00,  4.000e+00, -4.290e-04, -4.200e-03]],

#       [[ 6.900e-02,  1.000e+00,  5.000e+00,  2.740e-04,  4.030e-03]],

#       [[ 6.497e-02,  1.000e+00,  5.000e+00,  2.290e-04,  7.000e-05]],

#       [[ 6.490e-02,  1.000e+00,  5.000e+00,  5.140e-04,  2.000e-03]]])
y_train_array = np.reshape(y_train_array, (y_train_array.shape[0], 1, y_train_array.shape[1]))
#>>> y_train_array     NOTE THE NUMBER OF [ and ]   !!
#array([[[4]],

#       [[2]],

#       [[2]],

#       [[2]]])



model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(4,1,5) ))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: thanks for the update, there's an issue though midway with the reshaping of y_train after splitting it: `y_train.shape` >>> `(2320,)` ... `y_train.values` >>> `array([4, 2, 2, ..., 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64)` ... `y_train_array = y_train.values.reshape(4,1)` >>> `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2320 into shape (4,1)` . I'm also not sure why that shape in particular since the values for y are 0-4 which is 5 values.

Comment: you habe to adapt this to your data ie `y_train_array = y_train.values.reshape(2320,1)`

Comment: this reshape worked but it still throws a shape error on the fit line `model.fit(X_train_array, y_train_array, validation_data=(X_test_array, y_test_array), callbacks=[monitor,checkpointer], verbose=2, epochs=1000)` >>> `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (580, 5)` this is the first lstm `model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(4,1,5) ))`

Comment: you have to adapt this also to your data and reshape also the X_train_array. In `batch_input_shape` you can choose the batch size, for this reshaping like above `timesteps =1` and `input_dim =5` have to be left as is.

Comment: If you have the `validation_data` in the `model.fit` also reshape `X_test_array` and `y_test_array`

Answer (score 0):

The input shape is supposed in the format `(no_of_samples,no_of_timesteps,features)`

here you only have `(no_of_samples,features)`

You can use numpy to resize your training data before building the network

```
data = np.resize(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1]))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this creates data with the following shape `(2320, 1, 5)` but feeding this to the model `model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=data.shape))` throws `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_52: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

Comment: input_shape paramter inside LSTM should be `X_train.shape[1:]` i.e  `input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]`

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/  Getting the error : Error when checking input: expected lstm_70_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (38105, 30) using data = np.resize(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1]))

Comment: I’m trying to implement attention model on numeric dataset (non-NLP) and I’ve set the dimensions of my input and output (array) as: (1335,5,5) and (1335,3,5) respectively. where the batch size or total samples of my data=1335, Input has 5 features and output has 3 features to predict. Both input and output features are further made up of 5 values (as list) or elements, hence those dimensions mentioned above.

But I keep on getting dimensional error even for basic lstm encoder-decoder model.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) on recurrent layers:

> Input shape
>
> 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim).

In other words, your model expects your input to have an explicit dimension for the timesteps. Try adding an explicit timestep dimension to your with [`np.expand_dims()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Comment: updated the question based on this, shows the error that I got