# In Keras, how to get 3D input and 3D output for LSTM layers

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

In my original setting, I got

```
X1 = (1200,40,1)
y1 = (1200,10)
```

Then, I work perfectly with my codes:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(40, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add((Dense(10)))
```

Now, I further got another time series data same sizes as `X1` and `y1`. i.e.,

```
X2 = (1200,40,1)
y2 = (1200,10)
```

Now, I stack `X1`, `X2` and `y1`, `y2` as 3D arrays:

```
X_stack = (1200,40,2)
y_stack = (1200,10,2)
```

Then, I try to modify my `keras` code like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(40, 2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add((Dense((10,2))))
```

I want my code work directly with the 3D arrays `X_stack` and `y_stack` without reshaping them as 2D arrays. Would you give me a hand on how to modify the settings? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that there is an error somewhere in the shapes that you reported for your arrays. I'm guessing `y_stack.shape == (1200, 10, 2)`, is that correct?

However, here is one possibility to do what you describe:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(40, 2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(10 * 2))
model.add(Reshape((10, 2)))
```

The output of the network is created as a 2D tensor by the `Dense` layer, and then reshaped to a 3D tensor by the `Reshape`.
From an input-output perspective, this should behave like you specified.

Answer (score 1):

i can not give a short answer to this question however i think there is clarification needed about some basic concepts of LSTM (*one-to-one, one-to-many,...*)

As a superstructure RNNs (including LSTMs) are *sequential*, they are constructed to find time-like correlations,  while CNNs are *spatial* they are build to find space-like correlations

Then there is a further differentiation of LSTM in **one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one and many-to-many** like shown in **[Many to one and many to many LSTM examples in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras)**

The network type that is wanted here is point 5 in [Many to one and many to many LSTM examples in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras) and it says :

> Many-to-many when number of steps differ from input/output length: this is freaky hard in Keras. There are no easy code snippets to code that.

It is type 5 because input shape is  `X_stack = (1200,40,2)`
and output shape is `y_stack = (1200,10,2)` so the number of timesteps differ (`40` input and `10` output)

If you could manage to have an equal number of input and output timesteps you can reshape input and output data (`numpy.reshape`) like in **[keras LSTM feeding input with the right shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982179/keras-lstm-feeding-input-with-the-right-shape/51983035#51983035)** ( note the arrangement of the **[** and **]** in the arrays). This does not mean reshaping to 2D ( i.e. flattening ).
In https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/ is a complete example for building a many-to-many LSTM with **equal** input and output timesteps using `TimeDistributed` layer

Only for completeness, for *spatio-temporal* data there are also *CNN-LSTMs* however this does not apply here because two stacked timeseries have no explicit spatial correlations  :

If you have a 3D quantity, i.e. a distribution in a volume that changes over time and want to learn this then you have to use a *CNN-LSTM network*. In this approach both the 3D information and the temporal information is preserved. With 3D information is preserved is meant that the spatial information is not discarded. Normally in time-like learners like LSTM this spatial information is often discarded i.e. by *flattening* an image before processing it in an LSTM.
A complete tutorial how a (spatio-temporal) CNN-LSTM can be built in keras is in https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output tuple of `X_stack.shape()`:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(X_stack.shape[1], X_stack.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add((Dense((10,2))))
```

Comment: it will make it more dynamic, but it's exactly the same input_shape as @nam has

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will need to share the parameters for each array that you stack.

- If you were stacking entirely new features, then there wouldn't be an associated target with each one.
- If you were stacking completely different examples, then you would not be using 3D arrays, and would just be appending them to the end like normal.

**Solution**

To solve this problem, I would leverage the [TimeDistributed wrapper from Keras](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#TimeDistributed).

LSTM layers expect a shape `(j, k)` where `j` is the number of time steps, and `k` is the number of features. Since you want to keep your array as 3D for the input and output, you will want to stack on a different dimension than the feature dimension.

**Quick side note:**

I think it’s important to note the difference between the approaches. Stacking on the feature dimension gives you multiple features for the same time steps. In that case you would want to use the same LSTM layers and not go this route. Because you want a 3D input and a 3D output, I am proposing that you create a new dimension to stack on which will allow you to apply the same LSTM layers independently.

**TimeDistributed:**

This wrapper applies a layer to each array at the `1` index.
By stacking your `X1` and `X2` arrays on the `1` index, and using the TimeDistributed wrapper, you are applying LSTM layers independently to each array that you stack. Notice below that the original and updated model summaries have the exact same number of parameters.

**Implementation Steps:**

- The first step is to reshape the input of `(40, 2)` into `(2, 40, 1)`. This gives you the equivalent of **2 x** `(40, 1)` array inputs. You can either do this in the model like I’ve done, or when building your dataset and update the input shape.

  - By adding the extra dimension `(..., 1)` to the end, we are keeping the data in a format that the LSTM would understand if it was just looking at one of the arrays that we stacked at a time. Notice how your original input_shape is `(40, 1)` for instance.
- Then wrap each layer in the TimeDistributed wrapper.
- And finally, reshape the y output to match your data by swapping `(2, 10)` to `(10, 2)`.

**Code**

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed, InputLayer, Reshape
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
import numpy as np

# Original Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(40, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add((Dense(10)))

model.summary()
```

**Original Model Summary**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 40, 12)            672       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 40, 12)            1200      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 6)                 456       
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                70        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,398
Trainable params: 2,398
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Apply TimeDistributed Wrapper**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(40, 2)))
model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(2, 40, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10)))
model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(10, 2)))

model.summary()
```

**Updated Model Summary**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 2, 40, 1)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 2, 40, 12)         672       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 2, 40, 12)         1200      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 2, 6)              456       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_3 (TimeDist (None, 2, 10)             70        
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 10, 2)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 2,398
Trainable params: 2,398
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```